# this function should return a path to a given file or directory, but instead does nothing

Tags: python, file, debugging, recursion, directory

I am trying to build a simple program that uses the `os` module and returns the path to a given directory or a file (in code referred to as `target`) relative to the given directory (in code referred to as `path`).

What am I doing wrong?

```
import os

def search(path, target):
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        current = os.path.join(path, name)
        if name == target:
            return current
        elif os.path.isdir(current):
            return search(current, target)


if __name__=="__main__":
    path = input("path:")
    target = input("target:")
    print(search(path, target))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why not use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), which does the traversal for you and tells you the path?

Comment: Can you explain to me what you want to do? I can't seem to understand.

Comment: Basically, your code seems to try and check if a file exists. You do not need to traverse directories for that, just use `os.path.exists`. That being said, your code would not search all sub-directories in its current path. The moment it find a directory in the path (as opposed to a regular file), it will stop the loop, call itself recursively, and return the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code. It seems to me that it's working, you just have to use absolute paths.

[result of running your script using absolute paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6MGV.png)